# Submitted file is not moving to new folder using move_uploaded_file() , php

Tags: php, wordpress, file-upload

I have following memory configuration with **writable** file name-

```
upload_max_filesize = 256M;
post_max_size = 256M;
memory_limit = 256M;
```

and form enctype="multi-part/form-data", permission to the folder is 777(tried with 755 and 644 to). Unfortunately could not figure out actual error  -

```
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['async-upload']['tmp_name'], __DIR__.'/wp-content/uploads/'.$_FILES['async-upload']['name'])) {
    echo "File is valid, and was successfully uploaded.\n";
} else {
    // this always returns 0
    echo $_FILES['async-upload']["error"];
}
```

What could be possible reason for upload failure and what i am missing here?

same code is working in another project?

Comment: Have you activated error reporting and/or checked your error log?

Comment: yes error_reporting(E_ALL);

Comment: And you *have* checked your error log?

Comment: Are you checking `$_FILES['async-upload']['error']` anywhere in your code prior to the code you show us?

Comment: Try checking the access mode of all parent directories leading to the one, where you are about to store the uploaded file, for example with `namei`

Comment: I checked it for whether file is uploaded or not by php and  make sure  it's the only problem of not moving. @RiggsFolly

Comment: Then look at your error log as was suggested earlier. If you dont understand the errors, add then to your question

Comment: Add [error reporting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php/845025#845025) to the
top of your file(s) _while testing_ right after your opening PHP tag for example
`<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` to see if it yields anything.

Comment: No error and warning after prepending  `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: Nothing in error log @deceze

Comment: What's the path of your script's file, ie. is `__DIR__` what you expect it to be?

Comment: oh it's working directory.. @Joe

Comment: [`__DIR__`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) is the directory of the refering file. So if your upload script lays in the wordpress root directory, it makes sense. Try echoing `__DIR__ . '/wp-content/uploads/'` to make sure. Anyway you might want to use `wp_upload_dir()['basedir'] . $_FILES['async-upload']['name']` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Add an `M` to the numbers like this to signify Megabyte

```
upload_max_filesize = 256M;
post_max_size = 256M;
memory_limit = 256M;
```

And dont forget to restart your webserver after making the changes.

Comment: M is not missing while configuring thanks for remembering

Comment: In future please make sure the information you give us is an accurate representation of reality

Comment: Is there any possibility of server caching of code?

Comment: No, the server has only just received the file and as its InComing it wont be cached